# Java library for making sound effects on raw audio bytes without javax.sound.sampled.Mixer

Tags: java, audio, libraries

My goal is to edit audio data. I already unpacked data stored in .wav file by using `AudioInputStream.read()` method and saved it into a byte[] array. So I'm curious if there any libraries in Java that can manipulate raw audio data that I just got? I can't use `javax.sound.sampled.Mixer` because I don't have any available mixers. By "manipulate raw audio data" I mean adding a reverb effect, normalizing effect, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to use appropriate drivers. Or you can reuse algorithms used in Audacity.